# Currently messing with Swift Reachability, should I do all my code in viewDidLoad or in viewDidAppear?

Tags: swift

I'm currently trying to implement Reachability into my current project. I followed a tutorial on YouTube that worked but I'm unsure whether or not its the correct way of doing it. In the Reachability documentation (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) it shows two examples first one being 'Example - closures' where I assume it's done in the viewDidLoad?

```
//declare this property where it won't go out of scope relative to your listener
let reachability = Reachability()!

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
    // be on the main thread, like this:
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    }
}
reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
    // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
    // be on the main thread, like this:
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}

do {
    try reachability.startNotifier()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start notifier")
}
```

and the last example was 'Example - notifications', this is where I get confused the creator says to do that all in viewDidAppear. Is there really a big difference if I just do everything inside viewDidLoad? Does it change the outcome of anything? It currently works fine but I'm not sure whether it's right, I don't want it affecting me in the future. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: The big difference is that viewDidLoad happens once for an object in its life while viewDidAppear can happen any time an existing controller's view becomes visible.  Presumably, you only need to set up reachability closures once.  Whether you do the "start" once or turn it off and on when the view changes visibility is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

If you want to use `Reachability`...

- ... dynamically only if this particular view is frontmost, `startNotifier()` in `viewWillAppear` and `stopNotifier()` in `viewDidDisappear`.
- ... in this particular view as long as the view is alive/loaded `startNotifier()` in `viewDidLoad`.
- ... globally in all views put the entire code in `AppDelegate` and post notifications.